# Declaring foreign key constraint for two foreign keys from two different tables

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to declare constraint "fk" for two foreign keys student_id and subject_id from two different tables student and subject respectively.

I've alredy tried the following but it doesn't work

constraint fk foreign key(subject_id) and foreign key(student_id) references subject(subject_id) and student(student_id)

I cannot use two constraints that's why I am facing this problem. It has to be "fk".

Comment: A foreign key can only reference 1 table but you can have a many foreign keys as you deem useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two foreign keys:

**MySQL / Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE student ( student_id INT PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE subject ( subject_id INT PRIMARY KEY );
```

**Create Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table2 (
  subject_id INT,
  student_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT your_table2__subject_id__fk FOREIGN KEY ( subject_id ) REFERENCES subject ( subject_id ),
  CONSTRAINT your_table2__student_if__fk FOREIGN KEY ( student_id ) REFERENCES student ( student_id )
)
```

or, in Oracle, you can also use inline constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  subject_id INT CONSTRAINT your_table__subject_id__fk REFERENCES subject ( subject_id ),
  student_id INT CONSTRAINT your_table__student_if__fk REFERENCES student ( student_id )
)
```

> I want to declare constraint "fk" for two foreign keys student_id and subject_id from two different tables student and subject respectively.

You can't declare a single foreign key constraint which references two tables; the syntax requires that you only reference a single table.

I suppose, in Oracle, you could create a materialized view on the cross join of the two tables you want to reference and create a composite primary key on the `student_id` and `subject_id` columns and then reference the material view in the foreign key rather than the underlying tables but this seems to be a far too convoluted method to solve the issue. Instead, you should be pushing back against the requirement that you only use a single foreign key when the expected solution is to use two.